# Upgrading using pg_upgrade on windows fails

Tags: postgresql, windows, postgresql-9.2, upgrade, postgresql-9.3

When upgrading from postgres 9.2 to 9.3 by following the upgrade procedure found in [PostgreSQL 9.3.4 documentation about **`pg_upgrade`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/pgupgrade.html), the following command fails:

```
RUNAS /USER:postgres "CMD.EXE"
```

After some investigation, it seems there is no postgres windows user on the machine.  This causes the `pg_upgrade` command to fail as well.

How should I run the upgrade process?

Comment: Just use a regular user but make sure that user can write to both data directories (the new and the old one).

Answer (score 8):

Open an administrator cmd window as described in the link above.

Make sure you `cd` into an empty writable folder (for example, `c:\temp\somewhere`).

Execute the `pg_upgrade` command, and make sure to add an `-u postgres` parameter to it:

```bash
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\pg_upgrade.exe" -u postgres 
    --old-datadir "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/data" 
    --new-datadir "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/data" 
    --old-bindir "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin" 
    --new-bindir "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin"
```

Comment: Use -U (capital "U") for postgres 9.5!